# Feasibility of a 5000km tall orbital tower using active support

Tags: science-fiction, engineering, megastructures

Note: I'm working on a far future sci-fi setting for a novel series which aims to blend elements of both "soft" and "hard" science fiction concepts. I'm aiming for the series to be as grounded and consistent as possible whilst still allowing some elements of speculative physics. Most places in the galaxy are well within a post-scarcity economy, and any group or in some cases individual can afford a fleet of automated construction and mining drones if they so choose. Stellar and planetary scale megastructures are commonplace, up to Dyson scale and in some cases even larger.

The seedy capital of a region of lawless space is a tower almost 5000km tall built on an Venus-mass planet in the outer regions of a star system (*not a space elevator*). The tower, which we can provisionally call the Spire, was originally intended to be constructed to geosync orbit, but events in the distant past led to the abandonment of the tower and its subsequent takeover by criminal/corporate groups. The tower has a base 100 kilometres wide and makes use of active support and materials such as carbon nanotubes in its construction, and has a population in the hundreds of millions if not low billions. Much of the internal volume of the tower is given over to vacuum train tubes intended to bring cargo up and down the Spire. The planet's crust is robust and geologically dead.

Having recently come across an interesting Isaac Arthur video on super tall space towers (up to geosync, using active support and carbon nanotubes), my question is that would such a tower like the Spire be feasible with access to these technologies?

Many thanks!

Note: In this context, active support or an active structure is referring to the use of a constant stream of matter (such as iron ball bearings) to impart momentum within a structure to provide support, as in the concept of a space fountain. The main advantage is that this allows for very large structures without relying on compressive strength, with the main disadvantage being that constant power is required to maintain the matter stream.

Note 2: The tower serves as a kind of "neutral zone" for these groups, which largely self-govern themselves such as historical pirate enclaves, havens etc. Any form of combat within the vicinity of the tower is strictly forbidden and harshly dealt with.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. In simple terms, such as the concept of a space fountain, it's the use of a constant stream/circulation of accelerated material within vacuum tubes (such as iron ball bearings etc) to impart momentum onto a structure to keep it up, similar to the way one can use a stream of water to hold something aloft. I envisage a tower like the Spire as being built around several of these fountains which provide the necessary support.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I remember hearing Isaac Arthur on that subject, I'd forgotten. Thanks for the clarification. Could you add that detail to the question for others., as you know, comments don't last.

Comment: Not a point about feasibility, so I won't put it in an answer, but the twinned phrases "criminal capital", "lawless space" and the concept of a megastructure that requires active support seems like a short-lived combination.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I imagine it would be far from an ideal place to live, but such the tower essentially serves as a kind of "neutral zone" for these groups like a kind of self organising system. I'll add it to the post, but any form of combat within the vicinity of the tower is strictly forbidden and would be quickly dealt with. In addition, I imagine such a structure would be robust enough to shrug off some damage (considering it has to deal with radiation, micrometeoroids etc) and would also have an army of repair drones to patch up any damage.

Comment: Historically, at least, even places that were "neutral territory" but were nevertheless criminal centres and "lawless" were not what one would call "well maintained".  (See, for example, Kowloon or Tortuga.)  If there's an organization that watches for and punishes those who might damage the tower from the inside or the outside, that sounds... a lot like police, government, and law enforcement.  Particularly with a population in the hundreds of millions.

Comment: I understand your point, but I'm not aiming for the structure to be "well-maintained". As long as the thing isn't falling over or has catastrophic hull damage, and as long as the active stability system is active (both easily achievable with automated maintenance) then that should suffice. In regards to your other point, I probably shouldn't have mentioned pirates as I'm trying to avoid stereotypical "space pirates" in my setting, but I'm aiming more for a Omega-style arrangement (Mass Effect series), where the groups can do what they like as long as they pay tribute to the strongest group.

Comment: The question of support notwithstanding, having a tower that tall and that wide (i.e. that heavy) protruding from the surface might potentially have other implications: https://sciencegifs.csullender.com/2017/07/01/The-Dzhanibekov-Effect.html

Comment: at 5000km its trying o be a space elevator whether you want it or not, 5000km puts it inside the van Allen belt and low earth orbit. It may not functionally work like one but it is experiencing all the worst forces of one. The ISS is not even a quarter of the way up this thing.

Comment: @Nemactual As an ex-publisher, your entire first paragraph can be shortened to "I have magic." Almost nothing about this question or the question's background has anything to do with hard science. From the perspective of the [tag:science-based] tag, nothing about what you're asking is scientifically possible at this time or within a future encompassing potential advancements. So the question of feasibility is "no" due to the tag. Finally, for future reference, asking more than one question is literally a reason to close the question.

Comment: @JBH I'm sorry, but I fail to see the issue here. The actual tag description for science-based is "For questions that require plausible (better than suspension-of-disbelief) answers based on Real World science that are not necessarily constrained to the known limits of Real World science.  Contrast with the hard-science, science-fiction and internal-consistency tags." It is not aiming to be "hard science", rather simply a plausible answer based on real, known science and applying it to a fictional setting.

Comment: @Nemactual There is no real-world science allowing for the construction of a 5,000km tall object. At best, this question is [tag:science-fiction]. As tagged answers are expected to be based on real world science even if its application is stretched - but megastructures are entirely outside real world science in any and all ways. We can imagine them, but it's impossible by any stretch of the imagination to actually build one. Therefore "plausible" is impossible. "Suspension of disbelief" is possible, but that's not what you're asking for.

Comment: @Nemactual Before we discuss this further, keep in mind that 
Nosajimiki's answer is what you get with [tag:science-based]. You have no solution because you're expecting reality but asking for magic. More to the point, though (and this is true for every question asking if something is "feasible"), why does this matter? Are you going to drop the idea and not write about it because you're learning that as far as we understand science today it's impossible? Don't do that. Write the story and stop worrying about whether or not it's "feasible" using today's science.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up and indeed @Nosajimiki's answer is indeed what I was looking for. In regards to your point, I tend towards scientific optimism in terms of future technologies, things which are not impossible in physics but we currently can't construct with our engineering or materials science knowledge and of course new developments in physics etc. But I also want to at least try and keep handwaves to a minimum. You can handwave a lot of things simply by having a K2 civ. Such as a civ would have "magic" compared to us, but maybe it's a mistake for me to try and have a "grounded" K2.

Comment: @Nemactual Cheers. Keep in mind that the [tag:science-based] (and the [tag:hard-science]) tags don't share your optimism. They're literally meant to reflect only what we know today - which includes limitations in material science. There is no such thing as a valid answer concerning (e.g.) a Dyson Sphere with the [tag:science-based] tag other than, "sorry, can't be done." Scientific optimism is what the [tag:science-fiction] tag is for.

Comment: Hard Science means the answer must be supported by research and/or calculations, but the thing in question does not need to already exist.  All questions on WB.SE are supposed to be about creating fictional worlds after all.  Because my answer includes actual densities, material tolerances, etc, it's still a Hard Science answer.  If an OP askes "IF" a thing can exist with Hard Science, a negative answer does not invalidate the tag... though my alternate suggestions are for how to solve with Science Based/Science Fiction.  Maybe that is what JBH meant?

Comment: As for the distinction between Science Based and Science Fiction, Science Based is more like if something is conceivably plausible to someone with a firm grasp of science.  Active support systems are Science Based even though they don't exist because thier existence is based on mostly understood science.  Science Fiction is more for technologies based on technobabble, but are otherwise indiscernible from magic.  So things like transporters, inertia dampeners, FTL, etc. generally fall into the Science fiction tag.  They hint at real science, and then do whatever the heck you want them to do.

Comment: @Nemactual There's a pinned comment in [this video by Isaac Arthur](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8B2iqiKehyM&ab_channel=IsaacArthur) which links to a paper. That paper compares a few different kinds of active structures.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Not possible

For every action, there is an opposite and equal reaction.

The surface of your planet could not endure the reaction force of your active support system.  All of the force you exert upwards to keep your tower from crumbling under its own weight will also exert a downwards force.  When solid objects get into the scale of thousands of km, they stop acting like solids and act more like fluids.  Your tower would quickly sink down through the crust, burying itself in the planet instead of sitting neatly on the surface.

If we assume your tower has a roughly conical shape (the best shape for making a tall tower like this), then it will have a volume of about 39,300,000 $km^3$.  Office buildings made of traditional steel and concrete have a density of about 350 $kg/m^3$.  Using carbon nanotechnology, you can probably get about 5-10 times as much compressive strength for your mass as a high-end concrete and steel constructed building. So, let's say your tower probably has a density of about 35 $kg/m^3$.  This means that its total mass is about $1.3755 \times 10^{18} kg$.  The base of your tower is about $7.8540 \times 10^9 m^2$, meaning that the base of your tower will exert a downward force on the planet of about $1.5534 \times 10^9 N/m^2$, based on Venus's gravity.  Most natural stone has a crush force of about $1.8 \times 10^7$ to $6.7 \times 10^7 N/m^2$ depending on its composition.  When you exceed this force, the ground will behave like a liquid, letting your tower freely sink into it.  In other words, your tower is about 23.1 times as tall as the crust of a rocky planet could theoretically endure.  Probably closer to 40-100 times too tall when you consider the weight of the things inside your tower. So, if you want to go for scientifically believable, about 50-200 km is about how tall you can make a tower with that base to height ratio.  Even if you make room for massive improvements in building materials, the ground you build on is not getting any better than it is today.

**This gives you a few options:**

1. Make your tower MUCH smaller.  Works, but also boring.
2. Give your tower a "root structure" that gives it contact with about $3.2 \times 10^{11} m^2$ to $7.8 \times 10^{11} m^2$  of ground for the active support system to push against. Kind of a neat solution, but frankly still does not address the issues brought up in [lupe's answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/248731/57832)
3. Give your tower a MASSIVE subterranean empty space so that it actually floats in the solid rock of your planet following the principles of buoyancy... though this will violate some serious material integrity principles which will need to be solved separately.
4. Hold up your tower using science that does not presently exist.  This can be done by either making it out of some unobtanium allowing you to solve for the problems in #3, or use something like anti-gravity to negate the effects of your tower's weight on the planet.  This is probably your best solution because it is the least contestable in the case of a bad calculation or overlooked limiting factors while still making your super tower a possibility.  Also, you have described your tech level as being a highly advanced K2 civilization.  They SHOULD have all sorts of technology that seems borderline magical to us.  You can't conceivably advance that far and not invent stuff that flies in the face of our current understanding of science.

Comment: @Nemactual When you push something with a magnet, the magnet receives an opposite and equal force even if it does not touch.

Comment: I also wonder if the object is large enough (massive enough) to affect the spin of the planet. The top of Mt. Everest is 6382 km from the center of the core. The top of this building would be 11,382 km from the center of the core and easily 500X (if not more) the mass of Mt. Everest.

Comment: @JBH a bit, but probably not noticably so.  I's skinny enough, and much less dense than solid stone, that it should still only be a tiny fraction of the planet's total mass.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, this is great and appreciated. My original concept was more mundane and simply involved a large orbital habitat, but I got to thinking a decayed super-tower may be more thematically interesting. Of course, you've proposed some interesting workarounds and alternatives which I'm going to explore further. I think you have a good point about a K2 civilisation. As I mentioned to @JBH, I am a science optimist and I don't think our current understanding of things is the realistic limit, but it's certainly difficult to "ground" a K2 civ.

Comment: @Nosajimiki I agree with you... but it would make a cool component of a story (The tower is causing the planet to wobble like a weeble? What? The moon just went spinning off into space?!? Who's bright idea was this? *Who's Frank Lloyd Wright?*) And then there's the Anti-Hero element: Vin Diesel standing atop the tower holding his breath and with only his toes under a maintenance rail hauling on a 5km cable to use the towers massive centripetal force to bring a chunk of space debris up, over, and down on his enemies!

Comment: "Natural stone has a crush force of about, 1.8e6 to 6.7e6 N/m^2 depending on its composition". It's much stronger. Granite is about 140e6 in compression. Existing bulk-produced ceramics get to 3000e6 compressive strength. These numbers are starting to look feasible with pylons and perhaps secondary diagonal active members which can spread the weight further.

Comment: @KevinKostlan Opps, that was supposed to be e7 not e6. I've updated my calculations.  Yes, specific natural rocks can get up to 14e7, but not across a 100km wide area. At this scale, even bedrock consisting of high amounts of granite will have enough limestone and other softer materials in between that will break apart allowing the ground to displace at much less than 14e7.  Synthetic ceramics are a moot point unless the whole planet is a giant construct... which is doable for a K2 civ, but not specified by the OP.

Comment: As for pylons and secondary diagonal active members, those are already assumed in the building's architecture since my densities were based off of high-rise buildings that already take advantage of this sort of thing.

Comment: 5. Wrap the supporting base all the way around the planet like the roots of the wold tree art.

Comment: How about adding a huge number of helium balloons to compensate the weight?

Comment: @DonQuiKong most of the tower is going to be outside of the atmosphere; so, helium would weigh it down instead of lifting it up.

Answer (score 11):

## You're going to have a killer maintenance schedule

And, by that, I mean lack of maintenance is likely to kill everyone on the tower.

Assuming the base is made larger, as @Nosajimiki points out, the next issue is that active structures need everything to keep working. Imagine, if you will, the number of times power has gone out in your building. Now imagine if any time this outage lasted for more than a couple of hours, the building would fall down. Now fill the building with pirates.

If the power goes out longer than the backup power lasts? Everyone dies

If the backup power generators/batteries break? Everyone dies

If the HVAC system breaks? Everyone dies.

If the magnets at the top to redirect the ball bearings break? Everyone dies. Some by ball bearing grapeshot, others by crushing, some because a stream of ball bearings neatly sliced the bit of the tower they live in off

If the cooling system for the magnets breaks? Everyone dies. Some by ball bearing, crushing, etc, some by fire, superheated magnet coolant and minor explosion.

If the airlocks, walls etc break anywhere from kilometre 9 and up? Everyone dies.

The other charming feature of this kind of structure is that failures tend to compound. If a magnet at the top breaks, the ball bearings are likely to puncture a whole bunch of important electronics. Same with the magnets at the bottom. A loss of vacuum in the ball bearing tubes would lead to a mass of red hot ball bearings not quite making it to the top of the structure, before jamming somewhere and causing additional breaches.

You might have a fleet of automated constructor drones, but when some drunken moron in a  tricorn hat uses them for target practice, who is going to fix the critical power conduit damage on sector 5 caused by the exploding space-meth lab? Where do they get electronics they can't make? Raw materials?

Keeping an active structure running is a tough task for a functioning government. Make it some sort of space tortuga, and everyone will be dead within two weeks.

Incidentally, this is the kind of thing stopping us from building an active structure/space elevator. We probably have the materials to do it, power could come comfortably from a few dedicated nuclear power stations, we make some great magnets. But if it cuts out, it kills everyone in a neat line from the tower base

**Edit:**
I think I'd agree about the tech level meaning these challenges have been solved, but, most importantly, no one would be building active structures if you're at that tech level, because to get there you'd need materials that are strong enough to straight up build a tower, or some way of screwing with gravity. You're not going to mess around with a structure whose primary failure mode is to spray red hot ball bearings through the living quarters and then collapse.

Comment: To be fair to the OP, one of the conditions of the question is, "Stellar and planetary scale megastructures are commonplace, up to Dyson scale and in some cases even larger." This means everything you're concerned about has already been figured out. Can't have commonplace Dyson-scale megastructures and have concerns over a measly oversized skyscraper.

Comment: @JBH, mostly true... but this does sort of expose a problem with the OPs basic premise.  If you have such a civilization, then you should already WAY past asking questions about magnets and ball baring's.  Hard Science becomes a bit of a silly goal for a civilization that is well into K2 technologies.

Comment: I'd agree with that - also, if you can build a dyson sphere without it breaking apart, crashing into the sun, or otherwise fragmenting, the challenges of building a non active structured 500km tower are trivial. You have to have materials way stronger than needed for the tower for your other structures.

Comment: To which I think my answer should have been "Why would a K2 civilisation mess around with a means of building that is likely to kill everyone in it?"

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @lupe and appreciate the humour, although in regards to the Dyson sphere I'm more aiming for the "more feasible" Dyson swarm rather than a solid shell which I think may be impossible even with tech available to a K2. You raise some good points about the upkeep problem of any active structure, especially one on this scale. I'm trying to stay away from "traditional" space pirates, but its true that criminal (or at least "less-lawful) groups probably shouldn't be trusted with a magnetically supported accident waiting to happen. Thanks!

Comment: I can't argue with @Nosajimiki - from a worldbuilding process, all these issues would already be resolved. If the OP's premise of stellar and planetary megastructures being commonplace is accepted as a condition, then by definition the answer is, "yup, it's feasible in your world because you've already defined it to be so."

Comment: @Nemactual no problem, it was fun to write - I kind of love active structures, because of how hilariously lethal they are from an engineering perspective. Also, for the purposes of the description, I'm assuming your tower is about as law abiding as, say, florida :P

Comment: Thank you for elaborating on what I was driving at with my comment on the OP - anything that depends on active support really needs a devoted maintenance crew, which criminals and pirates are not exactly known to be.

Comment: On the upside "death by ball bearing" is an interesting and afaik entirely novel element in SF. Also, with regards to the lethality of active structures, see how [rotary jails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_jail) worked out.

Comment: You forget that such a tower would have redundancies. And those redundancies would have redundancies. After all, nobody would design a tower that would crash when you have to do maintenance on its power generator (so you have dozens of generators instead!). Plus a K2 civ would have some good automation (it is kinda hard to build megastructures without), so you don't actually need people to do maintenance: it could (and SHOULD) be automated.

Comment: @Negdo That is a good point.  When you think about it, macroscopic life is basically a super complex active support system.  If our bodies can turn our occasional conscious thought to eat into a concert of thousands of unique automated processes across 40 trillion cells acting together to stay alive, then something like this suddenly sounds a lot more feasible.

Comment: @Negdo I'd agree most of the maintenance would be automated, and of course, loads of redundancies. The problem for me is that, unlike the human body, which has some great systems for cleaning up and minimizing damage, an active structure is going to have failure modes that tend to cascade. A magnet fails, and you have maybe 10 minutes of high speed ball bearings already travelling before you can shut it off. A power cable is damaged by these ball bearings, causing another magnet to fail. There's of course stuff you can do to mitigate, but it's a mode of support constantly on a catastrophe curv

Comment: Also humans die, like, a lot, mostly from automated maintenance failures (see cancer)

Comment: Also also, humans die from the introduction of antagonistic elements to their active support system.  A drunken pirate doing ad-hoc target practice next to the maintenance drone storage centre could be analogous to standing next to a radiation source for a few hours.  A malicious maintenance engineer whose loved one was killed by the crime family ruling the tower and who wants to see it all burn could be analogous to  _Amanita phalloides_.

Answer (score 6):

@Nosajimiki has a point; your tower is impossible as written.

To get around it, you need your active support to come from a far wider base than just the 100 km square area you are talking about; it needs to come from a far larger base, perhaps 500 km square; so the down thrust needed to create your active support presses against a much wider area.

Perhaps you can discover that your spire is just part of a much much larger underground pyramid, completely occupied by the machinery needed to provide the active support, in fact ultimately the tower does not rest on the crust at all, as it appears, but goes down another 1000 km to rest on the hot mantle of the planet. If you want, that heat can also be exploited to power some of the active support; the pyramid is a geothermal machine.

Comment: TBF if your tower is 5000km high, a difference of 400km in the base size doesn't make that much difference. Assuming the tower is standing at the center, viewed from the top of the tower, the angular distance between the tower base and a corner of the square is about  0.8° and 4° respectively, It's an improvement but still quite small.

Comment: @Neinstein The point is to spread out the weight. Going from 100 km X 100 km to 500 x 500, we expand the area of the base by 25x. If need be, we can go to 1000 x 1000, and expand the base area by 100x. So the whole thing doesn't sink, tip and fall.

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas:

**The planet is a huge diamond**

Estimates for compressive strength of bulk diamond range from 3 GPa to 100 GPa. These are above the 1 GPa load at ground calculated by Nosajimiki.

Apparently [planet sized diamonds](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/science/article/diamond-the-size-of-earth) are not entirely unrealistic.

**Relativistic ion motors for active support**

Send a constant stream of water to the tower at low velocity, wide pipe. Use electricity to accelerate water molecules to near light speed before ejecting them downwards. This way the base does not have to bear the weight of the tower.

The energy requirements are pretty huge. For relativistic ion motors, thrust force approaches F = P / c as the ion velocity nears the speed of light. If we take the 10^18 kg mass estimate, this would take 2700 yottawatts to support, whereas the Sun's total power output is just 400 YW. A planet with lower gravity would of course make it easier.

This does cause a lot of radiation to wherever the matter beams happen to hit. It will also slowly use up the world's oceans, though with efficient enough ion motors this could take millennia.

**Fast spinning planet has low geosynchronous orbit**

If the planet had rotational period of 3 hours or less, the 5000 km high tower would go past the geosynchronous altitude. The mass could then be hanging from cables, like a normal space elevator.

Comment: The problem is not a planet containing a lot of natural diamond, but a planet made of a single diamond.  Carbon based planets would be made of a wide range of carbonates including calcite, aragonite, dolomite, etc with very little actual pure carbon the same way that our crust is mostly made of silicates with very little natural pure silicon.  Such planets could have a lot more diamond than Earth by comparison, but it would still be a relatively rare gemstone.

Comment: @Nosajimiki Yeah, it may need some hand-wavium to explain the existence of the huge diamond. The linked article seems to have one possible mechanism (white dwarfs), but who knows whether it is accurate. However the existence of such a diamond is well within bounds of known physics, even if we don't currently know of a process that would create it.

Comment: @jpa I'd argue that it needs more handwavium than the mere existence of the tower would need. To form a diamond, you need huge pressure. To find a Venus-sized diamond, [you have to look at the core of some dwarf star](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/BPM_37093) - but then where did the rest of the dwarf star go?

Comment: @Neinstein used by the K2 civilization